# why email id is not accessible via graph api even after enabling the option of sharing it in profile

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

My code is as shown below:

```
 facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogInActivity.this,
                        Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        //set login status
                        SessionManager.get(LogInActivity.this).setLoginStatus(true);
                        graphRequest(loginResult);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // not called
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        // not called
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

private void graphRequest(LoginResult loginResult) {
        showProgressDialog();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                        try {
                            if (object.has("email")) {
                                //store session manager
                                email = object.getString("email");
                                SessionManager.get(LogInActivity.this).setEmailId(email);
                            }
                            if (object.has("id")) {
                                faceBookId = object.getString("id");
                                picUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + faceBookId
                                        + "/picture?type=large";
                                //store session manager
                                SessionManager.get(LogInActivity.this).setProfilePic(picUrl);
//                                downLoadImage(url);

                            }
                            if (object.has("name")) {
                                //store session manager
                                name = object.getString("name");
                                SessionManager.get(LogInActivity.this).setPersonName(name);
                            }
                            downLoadImage(picUrl, name, email, "0");
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });


        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(small)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }
```

The problem here is , I am not able to get email id even after enabling **Allow friends to include my email address in Download Your Information** option in my facebook profile, is there any other way to get email id?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
String email = "";
try {
      email = URLDecoder.decode(object.optString("email")
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```